# How can I fix the error "Error: The pipe 'filter' could not be found! Error: The pipe 'filter' could not be found! "In angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I have a filter that when searching for a name brings me the data that contains that name, but it only sends me that error in the browser console.
it just doesn't show me the page

html

``````````
<div class="content">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 15px;" >
<div class="card_book">
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-body text-center">
    <form>
    <fieldset>
          
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filterPost"  placeholder="Nombre"  [(ngModel)]="filterPost" >
      <br>   
    </div> 
  </fieldset>     </form>
  </div></div></div></div></div></div>
     
        
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 15px;" *ngFor="let contacts of contacts | filtro:filterPost">
     <div class="card_book">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body text-center">
                      
                      <h3 >Nombre: {{contacts.name}}</h3>
                      <h5>Edad: {{contacts.number}}</h5 >
                      <h5>Email: {{contacts.email}}</h5>
      <h5 class="card-text">Fecha de nacimiento: {{contacts.date}}</h5>
      <h6 style="color: red;">Id: {{contacts.id}}</h6>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="generarPDF()">
      <img src="assets/img/descargar.png"  alt="DESCARGAR PDF" title="Descargar pdf"> DESCARGAR PDF
             
                      </button>
                    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
      `````````
``````````

ts here only goes this

``````````
  filterPost = '';

     `````````
``````````

pipe
I really don't know if the problem is here

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filtro'
})
export class FiltroPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    if (arg === '' || arg.length < 3) return value;
    const resultPosts = [];
    for (const post of value) {
      if (post.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        resultPosts.push(post);
      };
    };
    return resultPosts;
  }

}
```

It is already imported in module but I don't know why I get that error

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { FiltroPipe } from './pipes/filtro.pipe'




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FiltroPipe, 
  AppComponent,
  SendEmailComponent, 
  NavbarComponent,
  SidebarComponent,
  InactivityTimerComponent,
 
   ],
   
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule, FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, CanPaginaPrincipalGuard, AngularFirestore,DataDbService, 
   
  
  ],

 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: How did you import it in your module?

Comment: in app.module.ts I put `import {FilterPipe} from './pipes/filtro.pipe'.` and in declarations "FilterPipe,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to import it in the `nearest module` or `app.module.ts`

Please insert the pipe in `declarations` when you are using it in HTML (e.g. | 'pipename')

```
 @NgModule({
    // ---,
    declarations:[],
    // ----,
```

Please insert the pipe in `providers` when you are using it in .ts file (e.g. `pipename.transform()`)

```
 @NgModule({
    // ----,
    providers:[],
    // ----
```

Comment: @DEXcarlos, it is not always app.module.ts what is the nearest module to the component in which you are using that pipe.

Comment: I fixed it.
was at contact.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to register FiltroPipe in providers of `component typescript` file.
Then it will work.